# Having smaller images appear over a larger image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have 2 small shapes appear over one larger image; one at the top left & the other at the bottom right. So the picture should look like the below one:

http://i52.tinypic.com/j5cqw9.png

**My problem is that my HTML & CSS is not making the smaller images lie over the top of the larger image & the smaller images are not placed in the correct position.**

What am I doing wrong? *PS: is CSS vertical-align cross-browser*

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body { background-color: gray; }
        .col1 { width: 30%; float: left; background-color: blue; }
        .col2 { width: 70%; float: left; }

        #pastEvents       { background-color: red; }
        #pastEvents td    { padding: 20px; background-color: blue; }

        .pastEventDiv     { position: relative; background-color: yellow; }
        .eventBorderNorth { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 10; }
        .eventBorderSouth { float: right; vertical-align: bottom; z-index: 10; /*text-align: right;*/ }
        .eventPic         { position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 0; }

    -->
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="col1">
        abvdvf
    </div>

    <div class="col2">
        <table id="pastEvents">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div class="pastEventDiv">
                        <img class="eventBorderNorth" src="images/picBorderNorth.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/>
                        <img class="eventBorderSouth" src="images/picBorderSouth.png" width="30" height="30" alt=""/>
                        <img class="eventPic" src="images/1.jpg" width="100" height="200" alt=""/>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you float `.eventBorderSouth`? It should be:

```
.eventBorderSouth { position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: 10;}
```

So just like the left-top image, but then in the other corner.

Comment: When I take you advice, the south pic is displayed in the top left corner aswell. Are you sure I should be setting right to 0 & bottom to 0?

Comment: Yes, but I think you should remove the `position: absolute` from eventPic too. That image will then force the cell to the right size, allowing the South image to be positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a couple small things to make this work. First, get rid of the `float` and `vertical-align` on `.eventBorderSouth`, then add the positioning that GolezTrol suggests:

```
.eventBorderSouth {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Now you'll see that `.eventBorderSouth` is to the upper-left of the `.eventBorderNorth`. Why is this? Well, your `.pastEvent` `<div>` contains only absolutely positioned elements so it has a width and height of zero; the obvious solution is to tell the `<div>` how big it should be:

```
.pastEventDiv {
    position: relative;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Live example (with broken images of course): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MBGVX/